# MATLAB: Eigenvalue Analysis for System of Homogeneous Second order Equations with Damping Terms

Tags: matlab, matrix, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have a system of dynamic equations that ultimately can be written in the well-known "spring-mass-damper" form:

```
[M]{q''}+[C]{q'}+[K]{q}={0}

[M], [C], [K]: n-by-n Coefficient Matrices
{q}: n-by-1 Vector of the Degrees of Freedom
(the ' mark represents a time derivative)
```

I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this system.  Obviously due to the term [C]{q'}, the standard MATLAB function eig() will not be useful.

Does anyone know of a simple MATLAB routine to determine the eigenvalues, eigenvectors of this system?  The system is homogeneous so an efficient eigenvalue analysis should be very feasible, but I'm struggling a bit.

Obviously I can use brute force and a symbolic computing software to find the gigantic characteristic polynomial.  But this seems inefficient for me, especially because I'm looping this through the other parts of the code to determine frequencies as a function of other varied parameters.